# Daily Reputation Statistics

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, statistics

Is there any way to list users by reputation gained within the last *x* days/weeks? If not, could one be added?

*Edit post-reading back/reading comments and realising I sound terrifyingly like a stalker*:

I'm mostly interested because most SO users are way ahead of me, which makes the competitive aspects of SO a bit less fun. A daily reputation scoresheet would level the playing field somewhat.

Comment: You're a little bit too inquisitive, if you ask me.

Comment: How about breaking them down to geographical lcoations too? The timezone thingy as well, yea?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, does the re-phrasing make it sound a bit less creepy?

Comment: I am collecting data daily that can be used to generate these types of statistics. The import was pretty spotty last month but when I have a reasonable set I will publish a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reputation leagues are now rolled out:
https://stackexchange.com/leagues

Blog entry:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/network-central-stackexchange-com/

Answer (score 9):

If competition is your thing, you can redefine the goalposts to make it more fun.

I joined SO near the beginning, but didn't really become active until about June. I decided to compete by tracking [my page number](https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=8) every so often and see how it moved up. Even though my rep was low, I took satisfaction from seeing myself move from page 120, up to page 100, past page 50 and so on. I don't think I have ever hit the daily rep cap (so getting a badge for this would be really cool), but I've come close, and I definitely enjoy waking up to see my score higher (*"I got rep in my sleep! I'm a super-hero!"*)

So I'd definitely get a kick out of seeing more stats, but the [data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-dump) and [stackql](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=stackql) makes it so anyone can generate a lot of these stats ourselves.

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I started keeping track when I was on page 15 and managed to get halfway up page 2 before a change of job duties left me without enough time.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that a *daily* score-sheet would be a bit too volatile - and would also act slightly strangely due to different time zones (i.e. when people actually post vs the UTC day).

However, I'd be in favour of a weekly or monthly "league" - I'd find that interesting, certainly. It's been suggested before, however, and the tag stats were put in place partly as an alternative. I don't remember Jeff being *particularly* against it, but I don't think he was overly wild about the idea either. At the time, I think the overall leaders were much the same as the "recent history" leaders - but that may well have changed since the idea was originally suggested.

Jeff, care to run some tests and see whether it's actually any more interesting than just being a copy of the first page? (The ["no tag" stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=&sort=stats&pagesize=50) gives the last month, so we can all see that. That only shows votes rather than rep though.)

Comment: +1 for the no-tag stats page. And 29,962 upvotes is simply mind-boggling.

Comment: You mean 30,717.