# What's the maximum daily reputation ever reached?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

What is the highest reputation points a user of SE (I guess at SO) has ever reached in a day?

I know there's the rep cap at 200, but you can get over it from accepted answers and co. Is there a tool to out? It seems there was a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28965/daily-reputation-statistics) for such statistics, but its implementation was limited on weekly counts.

Example: I've searched the timeline of famous Jon, and found that on 9th March '12 he gained *871* reputation (because of a 400-points bounty)!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[MrGomez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517815/mrgomez?tab=reputation) was recently on a [bounty crusade](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127021/is-excessive-bounty-hunting-good-etiquette), during which he amassed **1225 reputation** on April 2, 2012, of which 1050 came from bounties alone, and 30 from accepted answers.

He didn't even hit the daily rep cap! If he had, the total reputation he could have earned that day would be 1280.

That said, I don't think there is a feasible way or a tool to find out the highest daily rep gain ever recorded. This is only from memory.

Comment: There are a couple higher, User 68210 on 2010-10-12 for 1338 is the highest, and 61305 on 2012-02-10 for 1228 being second...but some of those posts were later deleted so it won't appear impressive to the average user.  Also, there is a tool, SQL!

Comment: Is that info available in the data dumps?

Comment: @NickCraver: Interesting! Is this data/tool online available or do I need to download the stats and do that query locally?

Comment: @Bergi [Here's](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) a link, just click `Compose Query` on the top right. It seems the data is from Jun 26 though.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - no clue...I honestly don't keep up with what's in those, my guess would be *no*.  I wouldn't think we expose the RepHistory table Dalgas and I created as part of the reputation overhaul a few months ago...that's what makes querying this so easy and pretty much everything to do with reputation insanely easy compared to before it.

Comment: @Bergi - There's no tool...that's me hitting our SO production database with a query.  You could *almost* figure it out if you applied our exact rules, but exposing it'd be a ***crazy*** complicated query.  We have a denormalized table to store rep in as changes happen called RepHistory (also updated with deltas on a recalc, etc.) that makes things like this possible...but seeing as it includes downvotes with dates and such, we don't expose it in a data dump that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Geronimo: Thanks! I've searched that platform a bit and indeed found the query [maximum single-day reputation gain ever](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/72993/maximum-single-day-reputation-gain-ever). Yet, the result data is not reliable, none of the listed users really got that much rep on the stated day.